# Datadog task definition entrypoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-ecs, datadog, apm

Each time i add the entrypoint to my task definition to access the ip adress so the datadog agent can send me apm traces the service does not accept it and return failing status.

```
"entryPoint": [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "export DD_AGENT_HOST=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)"
      ],
```

Comment: that's the EC2 metadata endpoint URL. I'm not sure that works with ECS. It definitely doesn't work with Fargate deployments.

Comment: i am trying to make the datadog-agent access the private ip adress of the ec2 instance so it can send me traces. Its not a fargate deployment